# facebook app does not load in google chrome. Loads in all browsers ie until the works

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-iframe, iframe-app

I looked at the source code in the browser facebbok create a form over it within the code and this

```
<form method="post" id="proxy_form"> <input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="signed_request" name="signed_request" /> </ form> <script> document.domain = "facebook . to ";
   FrameName window.location.href.split var = ('#') [1];
   submitForm function (appTabUrl, signedRequest) {
     var proxyForm = document.getElementById ("proxy_form");
     proxyForm.setAttribute ("action", appTabUrl);
     proxyForm.setAttribute ("target", FrameName);
     var input = document.getElementById ("signed_request");
     input.setAttribute ("value", signedRequest);
     proxyForm.submit ();
   }
   waitForParams function () {
     if (parent.PlatformAppController &&
           parent.PlatformAppController.getFrameParams (FrameName) &&
         document.getElementById ("proxy_form") &&
         document.getElementById ("signed_request")) {
       var params =
         parent.PlatformAppController.getFrameParams (FrameName);
       submitForm (params.appTabUrl, params.signedRequest);
     Else {}
       setTimeout (waitForParams, 10);
     }
   }
   waitForParams (); </ script> <div <noscript> class="pam uiBoxGray"> You need to enable Javascript in your browser to use Facebook Applications. </ div> </ noscript>
```

my javascript is enabled and I I tested 3 different machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this code and it didn't work (only for fans) in Chrome either. For non fans it displayed the image correctly.

I just changed my redirects to a **HTTPS** and it has worked! :)
It looks like Chrome has issues with redirects to http. Just add an "s" to all of your links and it should work.

Be aware of hidden redirects, if you have a parameter URL or something like that, there you need to add the "s" twice: at the beginning (`https://www.myweb.com/r.php?`) and in the middle (`&url=https%3A//www.myweb.es`)

hope it helps!

An example:

```
<?php

require 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "384609344916003";
$app_secret = "f615dfb4c787d05d5f1a2fbefd11cadc";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];

if ($like_status) {

    if ($page_id == '1234567890'){
    // UK
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: https://www.myweb.com/fbpromo/");
        exit();
    } 
}
else {
    echo "<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='facebook_new.css'/>";
    echo "<body>";
    if ($page_id == '1234567890'){
        //English
        echo "<img src='http://www.myweb.com/img/facebook/FB-app-non-fans.jpg' alt='Like us' /> ";
    }
}

echo "</body>";

?>
```